# Angular fetch data specific to every item of ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, ngfor

I have an array of items which themselfes have a "foreign key" that can uniquely identify other items that are based on a server.

```
<div *ngFor="let parentItem of parentItems">
  {{(getChild(parentItem.childId) | async)?.someData}}
</div>

getChild(id):Observable<IChild>{
  return this.childService.getChild(id);
}
```

I would like to nest these items and display them.
Sadly nothing shows in the child brackets even tough the values are shown correctly inside a regular subscriber when logging to the console.
Also there seems to be another problem. The program tries to refetch it all the time. I think this has something to do with the change-detection, but i cannot figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
// component
public children$: Observable<Child>[]
constructor(childService: ChildService) {
  children$ = parentItems.map((parentItem) => this.childService.getChild(parentItem.childId).pipe(
     (data) => data.someData
  ));
}
```

and

```
// template
<div *ngFor="let child$ of children$">
   {{ child$ | async }}
</div>
```

Comment: This could be better approach instead get records while loop. By this way you have all the record in memory before loop start execution.